# Bash: Iterating over lines in a variable

Tags: bash

How does one properly iterate over lines in bash either in a variable, or from the output of a command? Simply setting the IFS variable to a new line works for the output of a command but not when processing a variable that contains new lines.

For example

```
#!/bin/bash

list="One\ntwo\nthree\nfour"

#Print the list with echo
echo -e "echo: \n$list"

#Set the field separator to new line
IFS=$'\n'

#Try to iterate over each line
echo "For loop:"
for item in $list
do
        echo "Item: $item"
done

#Output the variable to a file
echo -e $list > list.txt

#Try to iterate over each line from the cat command
echo "For loop over command output:"
for item in `cat list.txt`
do
        echo "Item: $item"
done
```

This gives the output:

```
echo: 
One
two
three
four
For loop:
Item: One\ntwo\nthree\nfour
For loop over command output:
Item: One
Item: two
Item: three
Item: four
```

As you can see, echoing the variable or iterating over the `cat` command prints each of the lines one by one correctly. However, the first for loop prints all the items on a single line. Any ideas?

Comment: Just a comment for all answers: I had to do $(echo "$line" | sed -e 's/^[[:space:]]*//') in order to trim the newline character.

Answer (score 455, accepted):

With bash, if you want to embed newlines in a string, enclose the string with `$''`:

```
$ list="One\ntwo\nthree\nfour"
$ echo "$list"
One\ntwo\nthree\nfour
$ list=$'One\ntwo\nthree\nfour'
$ echo "$list"
One
two
three
four
```

And if you have such a string already in a variable, you can read it line-by-line with:

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    echo "... $line ..."
done <<< "$list"
```

---

@wheeler makes a good point about `<<<` adding a trailing newline.

Suppose the variable ends with a newline

```bash
list=$'One\ntwo\nthree\nfour\n'
```

Then the while loop outputs

```sh
while IFS= read -r line; do
    echo "... $line ..."
done <<< "$list"
```

```
... One ...
... two ...
... three ...
... four ...
...  ...
```

To get around that, use a redirection from a process substitution instead of a here-string

```sh
while IFS= read -r line; do
    echo "... $line ..."
done < <(printf '%s' "$list")
```

```
... One ...
... two ...
... three ...
... four ...
```

But now this "fails" for strings *without* a trailing newline

```sh
list2=$'foo\nbar\nbaz'
while IFS= read -r line; do
    echo "... $line ..."
done < <(printf '%s' "$list2")
```

```
... foo ...
... bar ...
```

The [`read` documentation](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-read) says

> The exit status is zero, unless end-of-file is encountered

and because the input does not end with a newline, EOF is encountered before `read` can get a whole line. `read` exits non-zero and the while loop completes.

The characters are consumed into the variable though.

So, the absolutely proper way to loop over the lines of a string is:

```sh
while IFS= read -r line || [[ -n $line ]]; do
    echo "... $line ..."
done < <(printf '%s' "$list2")
```

This outputs the expected for both `$list` and `$list2`

Comment: Just a note that the `done <<< "$list"` is crucial

Comment: The reason `done <<< "$list"` is crucial is because that will pass "$list" as the input to `read`

Comment: I need to stress this: DOUBLE-QUOTING `$list` is very crucial.

Comment: How would I do that in ash? Because I get a `syntax error: unexpected redirection`.

Comment: I suggest you ask a new question.

Comment: `echo "$list" | while ...` could appear more clear than `... done <<< "$line"`

Comment: There are downsides to that approach as the while loop will run in a subshell: any variables assigned in the loop will not persist.

Comment: Whether  here-docs (the part following `<<<`) are evaluated in their own subshells may differ across bash versions.  Fore more, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/51181884/1054322

Comment: Let me leave a note and stress this: READING THE COMMENTS OF THE MOST VOTED ANSWER IS CRUCIAL.

Comment: There is aproblem with this: `while IFS= read -r line; do     echo "... $line ..."; done <<< $emptyVar` RESULT: `...  ...`. I would expect the loop to not run at all. [Mat's answer](https://superuser.com/a/284198/431826) takes care of this.

Comment: That answer iterates over the *words* in the variable, not the *lines*

Comment: Reading lines from `$list` variable worked for me to kill PID's but you would think there would be an easier way.

Comment: It sounds like `echo "$lines" | while read pid; do kill $pid; done` would be simpler, but depending on how the variable is populated there bound to be a better way.

Comment: IFS - mean Internal Field Separator. It is not obvious. https://bash.cyberciti.biz/guide/$IFS

Comment: It really works, but the syntax is very confusing to beginners...

Comment: @BBerastegui It would be handly for you to otherwise indicate which comment you want us to read. The "MOST VOTED" answer may or may not change as time passes.

Comment: Note: `<<<` inserts a newline, so if your text already has a newline, the `while` loop will run a final time with `''` as the value of `line`.

Answer (score 142):

You can use `while` + `read`:

```
some_command | while read line ; do
   echo === $line ===
done
```

Btw. the `-e` option to `echo` is non-standard. Use `printf` instead, if you want portability.

Comment: Note that if you use this syntax, variables assigned inside the loop won't stick after the loop. Oddly enough, the `<<<` version suggested by glenn jackman _does_ work with variable assignment.

Comment: @Sparhawk Yes, that's because the pipe starts a subshell executing the `while` part. The `<<<` version does not (in new bash versions, at least).

Answer (score 62):

```
#!/bin/sh

items="
one two three four
hello world
this should work just fine
"

IFS='
'
count=0
for item in $items
do
  count=$((count+1))
  echo $count $item
done
```

Comment: This outputs all items, not lines.

Comment: @TomaszPosłuszny No, this outputs 3 (count is 3) lines on my machine. Note the setting of the IFS. You could also use `IFS=$'\n'` for the same effect.

Comment: This and @jmiserez proposal both work beautifully, thank you!

Comment: This is the best option if your text already has a trailing newline.

Answer (score 25):

Here's a funny way of doing your for loop:

```
for item in ${list//\\n/
}
do
   echo "Item: $item"
done
```

A little more sensible/readable would be:

```
cr='
'
for item in ${list//\\n/$cr}
do
   echo "Item: $item"
done
```

But that's all too complex, you only need a space in there:

```
for item in ${list//\\n/ }
do
   echo "Item: $item"
done
```

You `$line` variable doesn't contain newlines. It contains instances of `\` followed by
`n`. You can see that clearly with:

```
$ cat t.sh
#! /bin/bash
list="One\ntwo\nthree\nfour"
echo $list | hexdump -C

$ ./t.sh
00000000  4f 6e 65 5c 6e 74 77 6f  5c 6e 74 68 72 65 65 5c  |One\ntwo\nthree\|
00000010  6e 66 6f 75 72 0a                                 |nfour.|
00000016
```

The substitution is replacing those with spaces, which is enough for it to work in for loops:

```
$ cat t.sh
#! /bin/bash
list="One\ntwo\nthree\nfour"
echo ${list//\\n/ } | hexdump -C

$ ./t.sh 
00000000  4f 6e 65 20 74 77 6f 20  74 68 72 65 65 20 66 6f  |One two three fo|
00000010  75 72 0a                                          |ur.|
00000013
```

---

Demo:

```
$ cat t.sh
#! /bin/bash
list="One\ntwo\nthree\nfour"
echo ${list//\\n/ } | hexdump -C
for item in ${list//\\n/ } ; do
    echo $item
done

$ ./t.sh 
00000000  4f 6e 65 20 74 77 6f 20  74 68 72 65 65 20 66 6f  |One two three fo|
00000010  75 72 0a                                          |ur.|
00000013
One
two
three
four
```

Comment: Interesting, can you explain what is going on here? It looks like you are replacing \n with a new line... What is the difference between the original string and the new one?

Comment: @Alex: updated my answer - with a simpler version too :-)

Comment: I tried this out and it doesn't appear to work if you have spaces in your input. In the example above we have "one\ntwo\nthree" and this works but it fails if we have "entry one\nentry two\nentry three" as it also adds a new line for the space too.

Comment: Just a note that instead of defining `cr` you can use `$'\n'`.

Comment: This is the most correct answer. The **other answers** will get into the **loop even if variable is not set or empty**.

Comment: "But that's all too complex, you only need a space in there". It does not work. Despite the fact that `${list//\\n/ }|hexdump -c` and `${list//\\n/$'\n'}|hexdump -c` are exactly the same, only the latter prints 3 separate lines. The first prints `Item: a b c`.

Comment: What happens if `list='one two\nthree four'`? How many lines should be output?

Comment: Much clearer than using `read -r` ... `done <<< $list`

Answer (score 12):

You can also first convert the variable into an array, then iterate over this.

```
lines="abc
def
ghi"

declare -a theArray

while read -r line
do
    theArray+=("$line")            
done <<< "$lines"

for line in "${theArray[@]}"
do
    echo "$line"
    #Do something complex here that would break your read loop
done
```

This is only usefull if you do not want to mess with the `IFS` and also have issues with the `read` command, as it can happen, if you call another script inside the loop that that script can empty your read buffer before returning, as it happened to me.